# Read Json into APK Asobe AIR as3

Tags: android, json, actionscript-3, air

I need to read a .json that I have within my .APK. I have tried many times I've even spend more than 1 day in it.

I think the problem is that FLHAS PROFESSIONAL use, but not want to give surrendered.

Nor loaded pictures new URLRequest(pictURL) :

Here are some codes that do not work on your phone (Android):

```
    var pictLdr:Loader = new Loader(); 
    var pictURL:String = "basecon/avatar3d.jpg";
    var pictURLReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(pictURL); 
    pictLdr.load(pictURLReq); 
    this.addChild(pictLdr);
```

And so I read the JSON and does not work

```
var tempFiles:File = File.desktopDirectory;
            tempFiles = tempFiles.resolvePath("basecon/conversaciones.json");
            trace(tempFiles.url); // app-storage:/images
            //file:///storage/sdcard1/basecon/conversaciones.json
```

Why?  How Can I read my JSON ?

Comment: Are you sure that json file exist on that location. Where is the code which loads the data from file?  Do you use JSON.parse()?

Comment: Hi, solve whit  [Embed(source = '/basecon/frases.json', mimeType='application/octet-stream')] private static const JSONfrases:Class;    ||||||||     var lasFrases:String = new JSONfrases();
   Storage.frases = com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode(lasFrases);

Answer (score 0):

The PO has done his best to ask a question in English but it did end up being a little off. What he meant is "how to read a json file", it's not that he can't read it, it's that he doesn't know how.

A File object gives you information about a file but not about its contents so trying to read a file with a File object won't work. You simply need to load that file and read its contents.

```
var tempFiles:File = File.applicationDirectory;
var jsonFile:File = tempFiles.resolvePath("basecon/conversaciones.json");
var fileLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
fileLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleFile);
fileLoader.load(new URLRequest(jsonFile.url));
```

Then in the handleFile listener:

```
var jsonData:String = String(fileLoader.data);
var jsonObject:Object = JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

Pretty simple.